# Syncing with Google

Tags: big-sur, gmail, accounts, apple-silicon, google-sync

I am a new mac user who owns Macbook Air M1 with **macOS 11.5.2**.
I have a problem when I am trying to add a **Google account** in my internet accounts to sync ***(not mail)*** with **Authorization Failed Error** once I click on **Open Browser**.
[image: error screenshot]

I tried changing my default browser to **Google Chrome** but no clue.

***Note: my apple ID is created using a Gmail account***

What can I do? I tried searching for solutions but nothing helped me and I need a solution urgently.

Comment: Could you try to login to Google on the same Mac and going [here](https://myaccount.google.com/permissions) to check what parts of your account macOS has access to. You could also try removing macOS's access to your account and login in again.

Comment: This is a list of apps which have access to my account, there's nothing related to my mac

Comment: Yeah, as far as Google is concerned, macOS is just an application. It's just a simple check to see if Google successfully handled the login request and macOS couldn't handle the response, or if Google couldn't handle the login request from macOS. If the former is true, an entry [like this](https://i.imgur.com/m0J0wST.png) should be listed, but based on your response it isn't.

Comment: So, what is the solution? :D

Comment: I wish I knew, but there's a reason it's only a comment. I was just trying to narrow down the problem for someone that might have a solution. Some other posts have suggested entering your information in *Other account* > *Mail Account*, or possibly using a VPN or a mobile hotspot, though their answers are uncertain.

Comment: I tried mail account manually using IMAP but it wasn't valid until I log in with a google app password but it gave me mail access only which I don't need, I am looking for calendar and contacts in the first place

Comment: You could try the *CalDAV* and *CardDAV* / *LDAP* (I'm unsure which) option instead of the *Mail Account*. Also just double check you can login to https://accounts.google.com in safari.

Comment: it's finally solved by using another network after more trials, Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been solved by trying different network connections until the authorization success.

I am not sure if the old network was just flakey but this solved itself server side or by getting a better network connection.